# Get generic type of Collection without checking an element out

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I need to find out the generic type of a `Collection<?>`. The only restriction is that I can't withdraw the first element (if it contains any) because of my caching mechanism - so I can't perform the following, because it actually gets the first value:

```
collection.iterator().next().getClass();
```

My goal is to determine, whether `Collection<?>` contains any other collection inside, for example `Collection<List<List<String>>>` is qualified, while Collection not. I receive this `Collection<?>` from a method call passed as a parameter. I have tried the following:

```
@Override
public Collection<?> execute(Collection<?> collection) {
    Class<?> clazz = collection.getClass();
    Type genericSuperClass = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType parametrizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericSuperClass;
    Type[] typeArguments = parametrizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
    String clazzName = typeArguments[0].toString();

    // ... irrelevant code
    return null;
}
```

Sadly the result of `String clazzName` is instead of `java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>` the following:

> E

My another attempt was to get it from the declared fields.

```
@Override
public Collection<?> execute(Collection<?> collection) {
    this.collection= collection;
    try {               
        Field field = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("collection");
        ParameterizedType parametrizedType = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
        Type type = parametrizedType .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    } catch ( SecurityException | NoSuchFieldException e) { ... }

    // ... irrelevant code
    return null;
}
```

This, on the other hand, gives me:

> ?

---

In case there is no way using reflection, is there any other tricky way to get an information, whether a Collection contains any Collection without checking-out the first element?

Comment: You simply can't. Well, you can, if it's a non-generic extension of a generic class (e.g. `class MyCollection extends Collection<List<List<String>>>`). But otherwise, no.

Comment: @AndyTurner: And difficultly? :(

Comment: I said "simply can't", not "can't simply". Perhaps it's not an idiom which translates easily, but I mean "you can't".

Comment: @AndyTurner: Oh, I got it. My mistake, I am not a native speaker. Thanks.

Comment: I guarantee your English is better than my Czech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Generics are a tool for making type-checking more useful at compilation. They don't exist at runtime.

At runtime, a Collection<whatever> is nothing else than a Collection without further information. Only its content describes what it contains.